# Android connect to BLE device from service (starts on boot)

Tags: android, service, ipc, bluetooth-lowenergy

My problem is I want to connect to BLE devices with their logic in .jar libraries from service(which runs as separate process). Currently I'm facing with next error. LogCat message:

```
05-19 17:46:45.107 14191-14203/com.<name>.rnd.erservice E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                                         at com.slsi.<name>.<name>.<init>(<name>.java:94)
                                                                         at com.<name>.rnd.erservice.device.<name>.<init>(<name>.java:28)
                                                                         at com.<name>.rnd.erservice.AppService$2.connectToDevices(AppService.java:184)
                                                                         at com.<name>.rnd.servicelibrary.IRemoteProductService$Stub.onTransact(IRemoteProductService.java:67)
                                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:461)
```

It seems that I need to start this connection from UI thread or from thread with Handler, but there must be no direct connection between application and remote service (kind of API calls to service and obtaining result). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has probably nothing to do with BLE. You can do GATT operations from any thread. If the library needs to be run on a thread that has a looper but you don't want to run on the main thread, you can probably create a new thread that executes Looper.prepare(), then calls the library and when that's done, call Looper.loop() to handle events from the library.

Comment: thanks for answer. Here's what i've tried:
`if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
                Looper.prepare();
            }

            handler = new Handler();
            Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
// do some work here
new Thread(task).start();
            Looper.loop();`
But that's still not working. Sorry maybe I'm missing something really simple, I'm new to Android

Comment: this does not helps.